# User agent stylesheet is overriding my css even though it acknowledges it shouldn't?

Tags: html, css

I've scoured the internet (and Stack Overflow) searching for a solution to this simple problem, but to no avail.

The user agent stylesheet is telling me that it's being overridden by my styles, but is still applying it's own. Take a look:

Original code snippet:

[image: Original code snippet]

Here, it shows clearly that the original `display:block;` is being overridden, as it should be.

[image: Here],

Yet here, under the computed tab, it is still applying display:block. The container is set to `display:table`.

[image: here]

I isolated the effected elements in scratch html/css files, and there is no problems with overriding the user agent stylesheet there, as can be seen here:

[image: here]

[image: here]

[image: here].

What on earth could be causing this? Thanks in advance.

Also, `!important` doesn't work.

**Edit:** All of the screenshots decided to embed themselves overnight so it looked like a total mess, which is fun. Rather than delete this question out of embarrassment, I just cleaned that up real fast, although it's still pretty convoluted-looking but whatever.

Comment: Could you share again a bigger screenshot for this image and not put any highlighting? https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSjem.png

Comment: Please stop sharing screenshots and post the code in a Code Snippet, fiddle, or codepen. Thanks.

Comment: Share your code snippet here @Riley

Comment: @webfrogs As implied by the fact that I isolated the effected elements and there was no problem there, the problem resides within my system, and therefore a fiddle would be useless. But here is one anyway. http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/FC7eY/

Comment: @BhawnaJain Is this enough? https://gyazo.com/9963a37aea053a44b236111544fc023b

Comment: @Riley I appreciate that you have checked the affected code and found no error. But showing us what isn't the problem doesn't help us figure out what _is_ the problem. We need (at least) enough code to demonstrate the problem that you are describing. Thanks!

Comment: @connexo: Substituting images *in-place* where they were linked to using words like "here" is never a good idea. It breaks the flow of the text completely and makes the question incredibly hard to read, especially when the images are screenshots. If you're not going to embed the images properly, e.g. with thematic breaks between paragraphs and adjusting the sentence structure to compensate, please don't embed them at all. The question was better off with just the links than with your edits - at least it was actually readable then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot of the element's computed styles, I notice that its `float` is set to `left`. Floating an element tends to blockify it, and in the case of a table-row, that does indeed turn it into a block and ultimately detach it from its table container, as a table-row cannot normally be floated. This is not a case of the UA stylesheet overriding your styles, but [how the `display` and `float` properties interact](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo).

In order for a table layout to work you cannot float any of its internal table elements, including row groups, rows, and cells. (You *can* float the table itself.) As I am not familiar with your layout I won't be able to suggest a proper and complete answer to your question, but the key here is to remove the `float` declaration from that element. Since this declaration doesn't appear in your own styles it must be elsewhere — look for it among the rest of the element's styles. If necessary, override it using `float: none`.

(There may of course be other factors causing this blockification that as others have mentioned require a proper reproduction of your problem to diagnose, but this is what I could glean from just the screenshots you've provided and is a very common and likely cause.)

Comment: Wow yeah, the float ended up being the problem. I never would have found that on my own. Sorry for the kind of bizarre way I asked the question; this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Riley: No problem, these do tend to be hard to spot. I was going to edit your question but I got sidetracked and went away for some time. The site does have a bit of a learning curve and some comments can get a little obtuse, though.